# Why isn't the number in my countdown timer changing?

Tags: python, function, countdown

So I'm trying to create a function that has a string with a number at the end of it that counts down sequentially. For example:

string = "This is a test."
number = [*range(0, 10)]

This is a test. 10 | This is a test. 9 | This is a test. 8 | ... (But I want it all on one line.)

This is the code I tried:

```
def comSpeakTimer(speak, seconds):
    count = [*range(0, seconds+1)]
    numbers = []
    timer = []
    words = list(speak)
    com = []
    
    for i in count:
        numbers.append(str(i))

    for i in words:
        com.append(i)

    com.append(' ') 
    timer.append(numbers[-1])

    convo = com + timer

    sentence = ''.join(convo)

    while len(numbers) != 0:
        print(' '*len(sentence), end='\r', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
        numbers.pop()
        timer.pop()
        timer.append(numbers[-1])
        print(sentence, end='\r', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
```

But the only thing I get is that it will print the <' '> then when it gets to "print(sentence)", it will just keep flashing "This is a test. 10 | This is a test. 10 | This is a test. 10 | ...". Strangely, though, when I print it on separate lines, it will countdown:

10
9
8
...

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `sentence` never changes inside the loop.  Why would you expect the print output to change?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
import time
def comSpeakTimer(speak, seconds):
    for i in range(seconds+1, 0, -1):
        message = speak + ' ' + str(i)
        print(message, end='\r', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(' '*len(message), end='\r', flush=True)
        
comSpeakTimer("this is a test", 10)
```

The function uses a `for loop` to count down from the specified duration.
In each iteration, it creates a message by combining the input message with the remaining time.

It prints this message to the command line, overwriting the previous message and pauses for one second.
After the delay, it clears the previous message, preparing for the next update.

Answer (score 0):

The most critical thing is that you are not updating the variable 'sentence' inside your while loop. There is also alot of redundant things happening but all of this can be simplified into a little less code such that

```
import time

def comSpeakTimer(speak, seconds):

    numbers = range(seconds, 0, -1)

    for i in numbers:
        
        sentence = f"{speak} {str(i)}.".ljust(50)
        
        print(sentence, end='\r', flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Updated my answer to pad the string with spaces, which allows you to omit the second print statement that prints a line of spaces.  Now you don't have to do that. One print statement.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I'm trying to create a function that has a string with a number at the end of it that counts down sequentially. ..."*

Here is an example.

```py
import time as t
def f(s, n):
    w = len(s) + 1 + len(str(n))
    for i in range(n):
        if i: print('\r' + ('' * w), end='')
        print(s + ' ' + str(n - i), end='')
        t.sleep(1)
```